# sed + replace key that begin in file with long text that include key and value

Tags: linux, bash, perl, sed

in `kafka.properies` file

```
more /home/kafka.properies
log.retention.hours=12
delete.topic.enable=true
leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds=300
leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage=10
log.dir=/var/kafka/data1
```

we want to replace the

```
log.dir=/var/kafka/data1
```

or any combination as

```
log.dir=/var/kafka/data1,/var/kafka/data2, ......
```

with $line

when:

```
echo $line
/var/kafka/data1,/var/kafka/data2,/var/kafka/data3,/var/kafka/data4,/var/kafka/data5,/var/kafka/data6,/var/kafka/data7,/var/kafka/data8
```

so we did the following:

```
 sed "s/^log.dir.*/\$line/g"   /home/kafka.properies
```

or

```
sed 's/^log.dir.*/$line/g'   /home/kafka.properies
```

but we get

```
log.retention.hours=12
delete.topic.enable=true
leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds=300
leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage=10
$line
```

instead to get

```
log.retention.hours=12
delete.topic.enable=true
leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds=300
leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage=10
log.dir=/var/kafka/data1,/var/kafka/data2,/var/kafka/data3,/var/kafka/data4,/var/kafka/data5,/var/kafka/data6,/var/kafka/data7,/var/kafka/data8
```

where I am wrong? , what is the right approach for this replacing ? ( with sed or perl one liner or other )

Comment: `sed "s~^log\.dir.*~log.dir=$line~"` ([demo](https://ideone.com/vL36JW))

Comment: I get log.dir/var/kafka/data1,/var/kafka/data2,/var/kafka/data3,/var/kafka/data4,/var/kafka/data5,/var/kafka/data6,/var/kafka/data7,/var/kafka/data8   ( but without the "="

Comment: Because you did not add `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```sh
sed "s~^log\.dir.*~log.dir=$line~" /home/kafka.properies
```

If there are any leading whitespaces, you may try

```sh
sed "s~^ *log\.dir.*~log.dir=$line~" /home/kafka.properies # only spaces
sed "s~^[[:space:]]*log\.dir.*~log.dir=$line~" /home/kafka.properies # any whitespaces
sed "s~^\s*log\.dir.*~log.dir=$line~" /home/kafka.properies # GNU sed only
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/vL36JW):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='log.retention.hours=12
delete.topic.enable=true
leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds=300
leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage=10
log.dir=/var/kafka/data1'
line='/var/kafka/data1,/var/kafka/data2,/var/kafka/data3,/var/kafka/data4,/var/kafka/data5,/var/kafka/data6,/var/kafka/data7,/var/kafka/data8'
sed "s~^log\.dir.*~log.dir=$line~g" <<< "$s"
```

Ouitput:

```
log.retention.hours=12
delete.topic.enable=true
leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds=300
leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage=10
log.dir=/var/kafka/data1,/var/kafka/data2,/var/kafka/data3,/var/kafka/data4,/var/kafka/data5,/var/kafka/data6,/var/kafka/data7,/var/kafka/data8
```

Note:

- `~` is used as a regex delimiter char here since the replacement contains `/` chars
- `.` in `log.dir` must be escaped to match a literal `.` char, else, `.` matches any single char
- You need to use double quotation marks in the sed command to be able to use variables in it.
- Since you match `log.dir` and consume it, this text will be removed from the match, and you should put it back in the replacement pattern.

As an option, you can capture the `log.dir` and use the backreference/placeholder to the group value in the RHS:

```sh
sed -E "s~^(log\.dir=).*~\1$line~" /home/kafka.properies
```

Comment: BTW , could you please add additional suggestion with sed  when log.dir start with space/s

Comment: @Judy I added at the beginning.

Comment: let me try on my linux machine